# Solvability conditions for a set of 2 ode's linked by continuity conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, continuity, nonlinear-system, boundary-value-problem

Let's assume that the you have :

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}_1 y &= \mathcal{F}_1(s) \quad s \in [0,1] \\
\mathcal{L}_2 y &= \mathcal{F}_2(s) \quad s \in ]1,2] 
\end{align}

where $\mathcal{L}_i$ are linear order 2 differential operators and $y$ the unknown.

Let's further assume that you have continuity conditions such that : 
\begin{align}
(1) :& y(1^-)=y(1^+) \\
(2) :& y'(1^-)=y'(1^+)
\end{align}

Does anyone knows how to adapt solvability conditions on that problem ?

Even if both problems are linear, when you stick them thanks to continuity the problem is no longer linear so I could not derive Fredholm alternative to get my solvability conditions.

Moreover, does an equivalent of "kernel" exist for the whole problem defined in [0,2] ?

Comment: When one speaks of applying the Fredholm alternative to ODEs one has to have some boundary conditions. And in your post you do not have any.

Comment: You are right when applied we use to have $\left\langle \mathcal{L}u,v \right\rangle=\left\langle u,\mathcal{L}^*v \right\rangle + S(u,v)$ where $S$ is your boundary conditions. My problem is not the boundary conditions but to ensure that some solvability conditions exist for this problem

Comment: I still do not see the context: what are those differential operators? on what space do they act?

Comment: Let's say that you have $\mathcal{L}_1= a \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$ and $\mathcal{L}_2= b \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}$. We seek for $y\in \mathcal{C}^0([0,2])$ and $y$ differentiable almost everywhere (Lebesgue measure).

Comment: So, how do you understand the second derivative? And, what is $\mathcal{C}^0([0,2])$? The space of functions taking the value $0$ at the ends of the interval?

Comment: In the classical way for now. I have introduce the continuity to search a way out without involving distribution formulation. I can derive some beautiful integral formulation of my problem with dirac distribution but it is not my goal. In fact, I need help on this kind of problem where you have 2 linear problems that you can solve easily. Then you linked them together at one point of your domain by continuity conditions. So " Can we still speak about operator in the usual sens ? " and "Is there any generalization of the kernel in this situation ? " and " What about solvability conditions ? "

Comment: $\mathcal{C}^0(0,2])$ is the space of continuous functions on the interval $[0,2]$.  For the boundary at $x=0$ and $x=2$ you take whatever you want. I seek a general formalism. So if you have any reference I will appreciate

Comment: If you are interested in a solution that satisfies one second-order ODE on $[0,1]$ and another one on $[1,0]$ and at $x=1$ the derivatives up to order one are to be defined, then the problems in fact trivializes: you take a solution of the first ODE on $[0,1]$, look at its zeroth and first derivatives at $x=1$, and take a solution of the second ODE with the initial conditions given by the values of the solution of the first ODE at $x=1$; by existence and uniqueness theorems, you have a unique solution of the initial value problem.